# Curl get Request not working with authorization token using php?

Tags: php, curl, oauth

I am working on api's to fetch data. I am trying to get response from api that have get request and need to pass token in api. Simple
Get request api is working but another api in which i ahev to pass token is not working. API returns response

> value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header

This is my code.

```
<?php
$headers = array(
    "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "Authorization: Bearer ".$responseDecode->access_token
);



$xurl = 'https://test.api.us2.abc.com/oauth/api/reg/number/?';
$query = http_build_query([
 'numId' => 10000,
 
]);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $xurl . $query);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$resp = curl_exec($ch);

$respArray = json_decode($resp);
print_r($respArray);
```

I am getting this info with getinfo

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://test.api.us2.abc.com/oauth/api/reg/number/?numId=1000
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 400
    [header_size] => 71
    [request_size] => 1109
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 2.884633
    [namelookup_time] => 0.001299
    [connect_time] => 0.712301
    [pretransfer_time] => 2.238987
    [size_upload] => 127
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 44
    [download_content_length] => 0
    [upload_content_length] => 127
    [starttransfer_time] => 2.239055
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 70.555.08.00
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 443
    [local_ip] => 192.167.83.178
    [local_port] => 52779
    [http_version] => 3
    [protocol] => 2
    [ssl_verifyresult] => 0
    [scheme] => HTTPS
    [appconnect_time_us] => 2238742
    [connect_time_us] => 712301
    [namelookup_time_us] => 1299
    [pretransfer_time_us] => 2238987
    [redirect_time_us] => 0
    [starttransfer_time_us] => 2239055
    [total_time_us] => 2884633
)
```

Comment: We don't know what kind of data `$responseDecode->access_token` contains (although of course we may be able to guess, but we cannot be certain). We also don't know what this API _expects_ you to include in the Authorization header - you provided no quotes from, or links to, the documentation.

Comment: Your `$authorization` variable appears to be redundant in this code. Is that intentional?

Comment: In $responseDecode->access_token variable i am getting auth token.  which i am trying to pass in api

Comment: Ok thanks. So just some random token value I guess? And what does the API's documentation say about what it expects you to put in the Authorization header? The error message suggests that you sent it something it wasn't expecting.

Comment: yes, it's random token value. I need to send this token to get response from api. Same token i ma using in curl post request's api and it's working

Comment: OK. Please answer my queries specifically about documentation

Comment: they have not mentioned it in doc. they have provided api to retrieve token and i need to pass that token in api.

Comment: If it's not mentioned in the documentation then how do you know a) that you need to pass the token, and b) what format it should be in? If the documentation is unclear on this point then please contact the maintainer of the API for support. We cannot really help you much if we don't have definitive guidance on what you are supposed to send in this particular request. We can see that the code isn't working as expected, but we cannot be sure how to fix it.

Comment: actually, it's clear to me because api is working in postman and swagger with token. Now, i have solved the error. but response is empty. In curl getinfo i am getting response i have updated above

Comment: What response do you expect instead? P.S. If you have it working in Postman, Postman can generate the equivalent PHP-Curl code for you, so you can ensure you get the exact same HTTP request as a result.

Comment: thanks a lot, it's working now. There was headers in postman that i was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you also have :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).